# How can I create a firebase function that disables billing on my application if the bill is above a threashhold?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I've read much documentation but all of them require me to oauth2 tokens or set environment variables to a json file that contains my credentials... That's nice when I run this locally, but how would I run this in the cloud? Such as firebase functions?

Comment: This is way too broad a topic to answer succinctly in a Stack Overflow answer, but Todd has recorded a video series where he shows how to do precisely this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NWrZwXK92IM&list=PLl-K7zZEsYLmK1tiMBeKA0iDMPDCJKM-5

Answer (score 1):

There is an example to [cap billing](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/notify#cap_disable_billing_to_stop_usage) on the public docs. Notice that you'll need to assign the Billing Account Administrator role to the runtime service account (generally the App Engine's default service account, but you can change that) for your Cloud Functions for it to work. As using the client libraries will handle the authentication and authorization automatically based on the permissions assigned to that particular service account.

Comment: Thanks. I saw this but I didn't like it do to this comment: "There is a delay of up to a few days between incurring costs and receiving budget notifications. Due to usage latency from the time that a resource is used to the time that the activity is billed, you might incur additional costs for usage that hasn't arrived at the time that all services are stopped."

Comment: Yes. That delay is unavoidable with this approach.

Comment: I wanted to just publish a firebase function that checks billing every hour for example.